# Populate Dynamic Drop down List based on String in Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I've been working through this guide --> https://www.xelplus.com/searchable-drop-down-list/ and I've mostly got it working, but it works on the premise of needing all these helper cells. I'm more of a VBA guy, and I'm working on somebody else workbook, which has helper worksheets so helper cells for formulas are OK, but what I'm struggling with is to make the list only contain items that are in the string in the cell (without a "helper" cell).

How can I make the search string, the cells value? Also, this needs to be carried down a column (D) so the "cells value" should be relational.

Example:

Currently I have a data that looks like this:

```
List    Formula SearchStr   DropDownList
ItemA           A          
ItemB   
ItemC           
FooA            
FooB            
FooC
```

My goal is to be able to type A in cell D2 and have the list options populate, only allowing the "final" value to be FooA/ItemA when leaving the cell, but I should be able to hit backspace, "B" and the list would dynamically repopulate.

Note: This is a "data-validated" cell in D2 with the following set:

```
=B2#
```

And the formula in B2 is as follows:

```
=SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!C2,Sheet1!A2:A7)),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Without vba you cannot do this directly without the use of a helper cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner If you write up an answer, I'd accept, otherwise I will. I ended up using VBA add-in from `ExcelCampus` which worked well.